# Show top menu bar when mouse enters a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dummy div and an actual div which acts as top menu for me. I want to show the `editor-menu-bar` when my mouse enters `menu-bar-dummy` and hide `editor-menu-bar` when mouse leaves `menu-bar-dummy`.

This code works almost fine. Its just that the editor-menu-bar keeps flickering. A quick debug shows that my `mouseleave` function keeps triggeing even when I move my mouse anywhere on `menubar` or `menubardummy`

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var menubar = $('.editor-menu-bar');
var menubardummy = $('.menu-bar-dummy');
menubardummy.mouseenter(function() {
  menubar.slideDown();
}).mouseleave(function() {
  menubar.slideUp();
});
```

```css
.menu-bar-dummy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  min-height: 55px;
  z-index: -100;
}

.editor-menu-bar {
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 zero-padd menu-bar-dummy"></div>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 editor-menu-bar" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 logo">
    <img src="./img/c.png" height="40px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your dummy div has no width so the `mouseenter` event will never fire on it. Also note that you can achieve this in CSS alone which would be a much better solution.

Comment: I was hoping bootstrap will provide width. Can you please post your css solution as answer?

Comment: mouseenter is being fired. But mouseleaves also keeps firing, even if my mouse is inside the dummy or editor-menu-bar. So my editor-menu-bar keeps going up and down, like its wobbling on water surface. :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This code works -

```
var menubar = $('.editor-menu-bar');
    var menubardummy = $('.menu-bar-dummy');
    menubardummy.mouseenter(function(){
        menubar.slideDown("slow", function(){
            menubar.mouseleave("slow", function(){
                menubar.slideUp();
            });
        });
    });
```

What was happening was, as soon as slideDown was done, the mouseleave for menubardummy was triggered, because menubar was coming on top of it. That was causing the bouncing effect.

new css (notice the z-index)-

```
.menu-bar-dummy{position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; min-height:55px; z-index:9000; width:100%;}

.editor-menu-bar{min-height:50px; height:50px; padding-top:5px; z-index:10000; box-shadow:0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08); display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

here i editted your code, hope it works for you

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>         $('.editor-menu-bar').slideUp();
>         $('.menu-bar-dummy').mouseenter(function() {
>             $('.editor-menu-bar').slideDown();
>         });
>         $('.menu-bar-dummy').mouseleave(function() {
>             $('.editor-menu-bar').slideUp();
>         });
>     })
>     // var menubar = $('.editor-menu-bar');
>     // var menubardummy = $('.menu-bar-dummy');
>     // menubardummy.mouseenter(function() {
>     //   menubar.slideDown();
>     // }).mouseleave(function() {
>     //   menubar.slideUp();
>     // });
>
> .menu-bar-dummy {
>       position: absolute;
>       width: 100px;
>       border: 1px solid #000;
>       top: 0px;
>       left: 0px;
>       min-height: 55px;
>       z-index: -100;
>     }
>
>     .editor-menu-bar {
>       min-height: 50px;
>       height: 50px;
>       padding-top: 5px;
>       box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
>     }
>
> <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 zero-padd menu-bar-dummy"></div>
>
> <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 editor-menu-bar">
>   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 logo">
>     <img src="./img/c.png" height="40px">
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: Please highlight what you changed and why/how it works

Comment: you must be doing something wrong @NalinAgrawal . i have commented all of your code and made new one and i am sure it is working. can you tell me what you get when you test it ?